# xslt define namespace only for the root node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing a xslt to transform a filemaker xml export to another system. I want to add a root node and define for that the namespace like that:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <root xmlns="http://somedefinition">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW" />
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
 <name><xsl:value-of select="fm:name"/></name>
 <name2><xsl:value-of select="fm:name2" /></name2>
 <street><xsl:value-of select="fm:street" /></street>
</xsl:template>
```

I call then another template. The nodes, that are created by that template get also a xmln-definition, which is empty. How can i prevent that?

the output looks like that:

```
<root xmlns="http://somedefinition">
  <name xmlns="">Lack AG</name>
  <name2 xmlns="">Freie Strasse</name2>
  <street xmlns="">55</street>
</root>
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is correct, because you're creating a `root` element in the `http://somedefinition` namespace and a number of other elements in *no* namespace.  To serialize this accurately the processor *must* add the `xmlns=""` overrides.

To get the output you want you would need to create the `name`, `name2` and `street` elements in the same `http://somedefinition` namespace as the `root` element.  The simplest way to achieve that is to remove the `xmlns="http://somedefinition"` from the `root` element inside the first template, and instead put it on the `xsl:stylesheet` element at the root of the stylesheet document

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
       xmlns:fm="..."
       xmlns="http://somedefinition"><!-- and any other required namespaces -->

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
   <name><xsl:value-of select="fm:name"/></name>
   <name2><xsl:value-of select="fm:name2" /></name2>
   <street><xsl:value-of select="fm:street" /></street>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now all the unprefixed literal result elements in the stylesheet use the namespace declared in the `xmlns="...."` on the `xsl:stylesheet`, and they will be created in the correct namespace in the output tree.  When the serializer comes to write out that tree as XML it can do so by putting an `xmlns="..."` on the `root` element only.

Comment: No, really, that **is** (was) the correct namespace.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I believe you, but given that the OP only provided a partial stylesheet in the question I wanted to make it clear that my response is only a partial `xsl:stylesheet` header.